# How can I remove empty paths from a zip file?

Tags: compression, zip, winzip

I have a zip file that contains a empty path, which I want to be rid of.  How can I clear it, while maintaining the rest of the zip?  When I open the item in winzip I cannot see the empty file, but upon extracting it, the empty path is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In older versions of WinZip, the empty folder names aren't shown, however, we can change that :)

- Open up the registry editor to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Nico Mak Computing\WinZip\WinZip`
- Add a string value called  `ShowDirEntries` (Right-click -> New -> String Value) and then set to `1`.

You should now see the entries in WinZip and be able to delete them from within WinZip.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that I don't fully understand this. When you open the zip file with explorer, it doesn't let you delete the empty folder?

Comment: I'm on Windows XP, and I can't seem to open the zip file in windows explorer.  I'm trying to fix it in winzip.

Comment: With the archive open in WinZip, when you right-click on the folder you should get an option to "Delete".

Comment: The empty folder is not visible in WinZip, should have mentioned that.  If there is a way to get it to show empty folders, that would help.

Comment: I found the answer John T suggested just after I incorrectly stated it works fine for me - go figure. You can also try this: go to the "View" menu and select "Files by Folder". This does work fine for me.

Comment: I would guess that the asker is using an older version of WinZip, which shows files as a flat list and not as a folder structure.  This is known as the Classic view in modern versions.  Empty folders are invisible under this view, thus can't be deleted.  Furthermore, I was just zipping up a folder and deleting a load of files in order to send back only the files I've changed.  It would be nice to be able to get rid of all the empty folders in one fell swoop.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Zip file with **[Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/)**, highlight the empty folder and press F8 to delete it.